# C# Passing lock objects to generic cache access method

Tags: c#, generics, static, locking, scope

I've got a generic cache access method inside a singleton class that takes three parameters.

1. a delegate (void return type with no parameters)
2. a cache label
3. a lock object designed to stop concurrent cache setting

See below:

```
protected delegate T GetDataMethod<T>();


protected override D GetCachedData<D>(GetDataMethod<D> dataAccessMethod, string cachelabel, object lockObject)
    {

        if (MemoryCache.Default[cachelabel] == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                //Inside the lock, test once again in case the cache object has been set already
                if (MemoryCache.Default[cachelabel] == null)
                {
                    umbraco.BusinessLogic.Log.Add(umbraco.BusinessLogic.LogTypes.Debug, -10, cachelabel + " inside lock, cache empty");

                    D data = default(D);


                        try
                        {
                            data = dataAccessMethod();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                          //Logging                               
                        }



                    MemoryCache.Default.Add(cachelabel, data, GetCacheItemPolicy());
                }
            }
        }

        return (D)MemoryCache.Default[cachelabel];
    }
```

I've got separate lock objects for each of the data collections that get cached set as static readonly objects. However, by passing them to the method their scope only exists within the method so the lock becomes irrelevant.

I can't use 'ref' as you can't pass a static object by ref, given that the surrounding class is a singleton, will it matter if I make the lock objects non static? If it will, can anyone recommend a better way of handling it without using a switch statement based on the cacheLabel?

EDIT:
Just for clarity the method footprint:

```
 protected override D GetCachedData<D>(GetDataMethod<D> dataAccessMethod, string cachelabel, ref object lockObject)
```

won't work as the lock objects are static. I guess the question really is - Inside a singleton, do lock objects need to be static to be threadsafe? (Yes, it's a thread safe singleton)

Comment: Using a ConcurrentDictionary for your cache would relieve you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx  unless of course your question is just a thought exercise.

Comment: `their scope only exists within the method`:: your lock objects are reference types aren't they? If so, can you explain what you mean any more?

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far guys. You can't pass a static object by ref, if I remove the static declaration, doesn't that negate the point of the lock object? Or, given the fact that the method is in a singleton negate that negation...

It's more than a thought exercise, the setters for the MemoryCache object aren't thread safe (as I found out to my own pain), and the data request takes quite a bit of time through EF so I need to lock the setter method to prevent multiple threads filling the various cache items (hence the two stage check - once before the lock, and once inside the lock)

Comment: @TimRogers I've edited the original question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of the `ref` keyword - you don't need it. You're passing an `object` which is already a reference type. Adding the `ref` keyword will make it a reference to a reference.

Comment: Apologies for this question, notenough coffee, and too much time spent looking at the same 8 lines of code turned off my brain...